# How should I build a C++ app for distribution to different versions of OS X/macOS?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang, abi

I know that certain versions of the compiler will break the C++ ABI, but I don't know which versions.

Would I need to use a different version of Xcode for each OS version that I want to support? If so, which versions of Xcode should I use?

Comment: Xcode comes with an OSX SDK.  Each SDK documents which versions of OSX it is compatible with.  Usually macros can be used to hide APIs from "more modern" OS's than the one you are targetting.  You will have to be more specific if you want an easy answer; your question requires a reasonably large table and significant reseach, far more work than your probable practical problem, and the table becomes out of date every few months.

Comment: I would probably want to limit the number of builds. If I choose to support the most recent three ABIs, do you know what I should use for the three builds?

Comment: I just realized I have no idea what you want.  Do you mean 3 latest OS versions?  3 latest calling conventions (!)?  3 latest abi breaks in stdlib?  3 latest versions of C++?  Please be more specific.

Comment: If I understand it, I would need to do another build for anything that breaks the ABI. So my problem becomes how to identify those versions of Xcode. I can go through the SDK documents you mentioned. I was hoping the three builds would support the three most recent versions of the OS.

Comment: Usually one build can support 3 versions of OS/X.  Grab the latest xcode, set preprocessor tokens right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be expecting the kinds of C++ compiler/ABI compatibility issues that are common on Linux. OS X/macOS largely doesn't have issues like these--you can build a binary against the latest SDK (10.13), and set the deployment target to the oldest OS version you want to support (i.e. 10.10). The resulting binary will work on 10.10 and up, there's no need to build multiple binaries for different OS versions.

On the command line, the deployment target can be set using `-mmacosx-min-version=`. The compiler will even error out if you try to use a library/language feature that is not available on the target version (like `std::shared_timed_mutex`, a new C++14 feature). Note that some new language features (like `std::make_unique` here) are implemented in the compiler/headers, so the older library is not a problem:

```
$ cat test5.cpp
#include <memory>
#include <shared_mutex>

int main()
{
    auto x = std::make_unique<int>(3);
    printf("%d\n", *x);
    std::shared_timed_mutex y;
    return 0;
}
$ clang++ -std=c++14 -o test5 test5.cpp -mmacosx-version-min=10.9
test5.cpp:8:7: error: 'shared_timed_mutex' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.12
        std::shared_timed_mutex y;
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/shared_mutex:204:58: note: 'shared_timed_mutex' has been
      explicitly marked unavailable here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS _LIBCPP_AVAILABILITY_SHARED_MUTEX shared_timed_mutex
                                                         ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm thinking of the Itanium C++ ABI that the installed libc++ library is built for. Even if an app targets an old SDK, my understanding is that there is only one /usr/lib/libc++.dylib installed by default on the system. I thought that all apps using C++, regardless of the target SDK selected for the app, had to use the same libc++.dylib. But this is interesting - How would an app use a different libc++.dylib?

Comment: Yes, all apps use the single libc++ that ships with the system. But, the ABI is kept compatible between versions, and the compiler/linker knows what C++ features will be available in the targeted libc++ and to make a binary compatible with that version. I edited my post to show an example (and when I built a binary on 10.13 targeting 10.9, it does run on 10.9)

Comment: This is good info, thanks. I will look it over more tonight. But one question - you said "the ABI is kept compatible between versions" are you saying that libc++ installed on 10.10 uses the same ABI as libc++ installed on 10.13? Or that the C++ ABIs are different but compatible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Qt answers the question with their table of "Supported configurations for Qt 5.10"

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/supported-platforms.html

The three builds would use:

Xcode 8.2 (macOS 10.11)

Xcode 8.3.3 (macOS 10.12)

Xcode 9 (macOS 10.13)